# stat not working

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am writing a file watcher and stat for some reason cant get a hold of file information, why?

```
struct stat info;
int fd = open(path, O_EVTONLY);
if (fd <= 0){
    exit(-1);
}
int result = fstat(fd, &info);
if (!result){
    exit(-1); //This happens! Errno says "No such file or directory" but that cant be because open would've failed
}
```

Comment: @wildplasser yea, i used it, just mistyped here

Comment: Well, don't mistype than. People could react to the wrong error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int result = fstat(fd, &info);
if (!result){
    exit(-1);
}
```

Check `fstat` man page, on success 0 is returned.

Answer (score 3):

[`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) returns zero on success, as do most standard libc functions.

This is designed as such, so you can easily check for errors in a chain of library calls:

```
if (stat(fd, &info)) {
    perror("stat");
    exit(1);
}
//stat succeeded.

if (...) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your usage, I assume you want fstat(). fstat() takes a fd as argument, stat() a string.